# Dask with tensor flow is failing with `CRITICAL - Failed to Serialize` error

Tags: python-3.x, dask, dask-distributed, dask-ml

I have installed dask[complete], tensorflow, scikeras, deplayed, dask-ml.
I am running the same example [link](https://ml.dask.org/keras.html) in my local. There are no stack traces in worker logs as well. Please help me with inputs to degug further.

The code is failing with following error :

```
distributed.protocol.core - CRITICAL - Failed to Serialize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py", line 70, in dumps
    frames[0] = msgpack.dumps(msg, default=_encode_default, use_bin_type=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/msgpack/__init__.py", line 35, in packb
    return Packer(**kwargs).pack(o)
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 292, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 298, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 295, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 264, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 229, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 264, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 289, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
TypeError: can not serialize 'Delayed' object
distributed.comm.utils - ERROR - can not serialize 'Delayed' object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/comm/utils.py", line 32, in _to_frames
    msg, serializers=serializers, on_error=on_error, context=context
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py", line 70, in dumps
    frames[0] = msgpack.dumps(msg, default=_encode_default, use_bin_type=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/msgpack/__init__.py", line 35, in packb
    return Packer(**kwargs).pack(o)
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 292, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 298, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 295, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 264, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 229, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 264, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 289, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
TypeError: can not serialize 'Delayed' object
distributed.batched - ERROR - Error in batched write
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/batched.py", line 94, in _background_send
    payload, serializers=self.serializers, on_error="raise"
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/comm/tcp.py", line 243, in write
    **self.handshake_options,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/comm/utils.py", line 51, in to_frames
    return _to_frames()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/comm/utils.py", line 32, in _to_frames
    msg, serializers=serializers, on_error=on_error, context=context
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py", line 70, in dumps
    frames[0] = msgpack.dumps(msg, default=_encode_default, use_bin_type=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/msgpack/__init__.py", line 35, in packb
    return Packer(**kwargs).pack(o)
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 292, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 298, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 295, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 264, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 229, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 264, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 289, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
TypeError: can not serialize 'Delayed' object
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I think there's a chance this isn't SciKeras / TensorFlow specific. I opened https://github.com/dask/dask-ml/issues/828 with what I think is a minimal example

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this is a bug in dask-ml: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/7571

Updating to the latest version (currently unpublished, you'd have to install from GitHub) seems to solve the problem:

```sh
$ pip install git+https://github.com/dask/dask-ml.git
```

Comment: They've released a fix: https://pypi.org/project/dask-ml/1.9.0/